# Can I make Eclipse Helios organize imports with blank lines between subpackage imports?

Tags: eclipse, helios

This falls into the obsessive-compulsive programmer bucket.

I have developed a fondness for separating imports by package with blank lines.  So:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.sql.SQLException;
```

...instead of:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

I can easily make Eclipse do the latter using their preferences dialog.  And I can make Eclipse do the former if I know in advance what the packages are going to be, since Eclipse inserts a blank line by default after each import group.

My question is: is there any way to tell Eclipse to insert a blank line between *sub* packages automatically?

Comment: I know you can do this on Intellij idea but not in eclipse I am also looking for a way to do it :<

Answer (score 0):

You should use in organize imports separated fields for every packages if you want insert blank line between them like:

```
java.io.*
java.sql.*
```